# glm function causes a strange change in data frame

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm working on a data set of IBM by using `quantmod`. I created two variables and then I used the `glm` function to see the relation between the two of them. The code ran good but then I noticed that part of the data frame contains `NA`s. How can I overcome this issue?
Here is my code:

```
library("quantmod")
getSymbols("IBM")
dim(IBM)
IBM$CurrtDay_up <- ifelse(IBM$IBM.Open < IBM$IBM.Close,1,0)
IBM$LastDay_green <- ifelse((lag(IBM$IBM.Open,k=1) < lag(IBM$IBM.Close,k=1)),1,0)
head(IBM)
           IBM.Open IBM.High IBM.Low IBM.Close IBM.Volume IBM.Adjusted CurrtDay_up LastDay_green
2007-01-03    97.18    98.40   96.26     97.27    9196800     82.78498           1            NA
2007-01-04    97.25    98.79   96.88     98.31   10524500     83.67011           1             1
2007-01-05    97.60    97.95   96.91     97.42    7221300     82.91264           0             1
2007-01-08    98.50    99.50   98.35     98.90   10340000     84.17225           1             0
2007-01-09    99.08   100.33   99.07    100.07   11108200     85.16802           1             1
2007-01-10    98.50    99.05   97.93     98.89    8744800     84.16374           1             1
```

then I added the `glm` function:

```
IBM_1 <- IBM[3:1000,] # to avoid the first row's NA.
glm_greenDay <- glm(CurrtDay_up~LastDay_green,data=IBM_1,family=binomial(link='logit'))
IBM_1$glm_pred<-predict(glm_greenDay,newdata=IBM_1,type='response')
head(IBM_1)
           IBM.Open IBM.High IBM.Low IBM.Close IBM.Volume IBM.Adjusted CurrtDay_up LastDay_green  glm_pred
2007-01-04       NA       NA      NA        NA         NA           NA          NA            NA 0.5683453
2007-01-05    97.60    97.95   96.91     97.42    7221300     82.91264           0             1        NA
2007-01-07       NA       NA      NA        NA         NA           NA          NA            NA 0.5407240
2007-01-08    98.50    99.50   98.35     98.90   10340000     84.17225           1             0        NA
2007-01-08       NA       NA      NA        NA         NA           NA          NA            NA 0.5683453
2007-01-09    99.08   100.33   99.07    100.07   11108200     85.16802           1             1        NA
```

UPDATED CODE (please notice that one row (row # 2) has been duplicated: :

```
 IBM_1<-IBM[complete.cases(IBM[1:1000,]),] # to evoid the first row's NA.
 glm_greenDay<-glm(CurrtDay_up~LastDay_green,data=IBM_1,family=binomial(link='logit'))
 IBM_1$glm_pred<-glm_greenDay$fitted.values
 head(IBM_1)
           IBM.Open IBM.High IBM.Low IBM.Close IBM.Volume IBM.Adjusted CurrtDay_up LastDay_green  glm_pred
2007-01-03       NA       NA      NA        NA         NA           NA          NA            NA 0.5691203
2007-01-04    97.25    98.79   96.88     98.31   10524500     83.67011           1             1        NA
2007-01-04       NA       NA      NA        NA         NA           NA          NA            NA 0.5691203
2007-01-05    97.60    97.95   96.91     97.42    7221300     82.91264           0             1        NA
2007-01-07       NA       NA      NA        NA         NA           NA          NA            NA 0.5407240
2007-01-08    98.50    99.50   98.35     98.90   10340000     84.17225           1             0        NA
```

Comment: why not use `IBM_1$glm_pred <- glm_greenDay$fitted.values`? And to avoid NA use `IBM_1 <- IBM[complete.cases(IBM),]`

Comment: Thanks @Andriy, I tried IBM_1$glm_pred <- glm_greenDay$fitted.values but I got again a data frame live above: I added the code and results as an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is arising because the output of `predict()` is not an `xts` class object. The slots in the vector of predicted values have dates for names, but the vector is still just a vector without time indexing. I was able to get a simple call to `merge()` to work without dropping NAs before modeling by converting the output of `predict()` to class `xts` first:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("IBM")
IBM$CurrtDay_up <- ifelse(IBM$IBM.Open < IBM$IBM.Close, 1, 0)
IBM$LastDay_green <- ifelse((lag(IBM$IBM.Open, k=1) < lag(IBM$IBM.Close, k=1)), 1, 0)
glm_greenDay <- glm(CurrtDay_up~LastDay_green, data=IBM, family=binomial(link='logit'), na.action=na.exclude)
glm_pred <- predict(glm_greenDay, type='response')
glm_pred_xts <- xts(x = glm_pred, order.by = as.Date(names(glm_pred)))
IBM2 <- merge(IBM, glm_pred_xts)
```

That seems to produce the desired output:

```
> head(glm_pred)
2007-01-03 2007-01-04 2007-01-05 2007-01-08 2007-01-09 2007-01-10 
        NA  0.5383952  0.5383952  0.5383065  0.5383952  0.5383952 

> head(IBM2)
           IBM.Open IBM.High IBM.Low IBM.Close IBM.Volume IBM.Adjusted CurrtDay_up LastDay_green glm_pred_xts
2007-01-03    97.18    98.40   96.26     97.27    9196800     82.78498           1            NA           NA
2007-01-04    97.25    98.79   96.88     98.31   10524500     83.67011           1             1    0.5383952
2007-01-05    97.60    97.95   96.91     97.42    7221300     82.91264           0             1    0.5383952
2007-01-08    98.50    99.50   98.35     98.90   10340000     84.17225           1             0    0.5383065
2007-01-09    99.08   100.33   99.07    100.07   11108200     85.16802           1             1    0.5383952
2007-01-10    98.50    99.05   97.93     98.89    8744800     84.16374           1             1    0.5383952
```

Comment: Thanks ulfelder, would you say that your solution with the xts object is equal to data.frame or matrix solutions that wre written above or the use of xts object will be better for the dev procces in the future?

Comment: If you're going to want to take advantage of other `quantmod` or `xts` features past this step, then I think you want to go this route and put your model output into the xts object. If you don't care about those features and are only using `quantmod`to get the price data, then it's probably easier to convert the original xts object returned by `getSymbols("IBM")` to a data frame before the call to `glm()` and then just proceed with the typical data.frame options.

Answer (score 1):

Might be how you're constructing your final data frame and how R handles NAs.

The way I read your code you're adding the result column to the data frame with:

```
IBM_1$glm_pred<-glm_greenDay$fitted.values
```

You might be able to throw your result into a separate object and use `cbind` to attach it to the rest of your data frame without propagating the NAs across columns

Maybe...

```
glm_pred<-matrix(glm_greenDay$fitted.values,ncol=1)
IBM_glm<-cbind(IBM_1,glm_pred)
```

Don't know if it's the most elegant but might be a start.

Comment: Well, this works, Thanks Draguru.One thing:I get a strange column name :  "..2"  Is there any reason for that ?

Comment: "..2" is the column name for the added  `glm_pred` column?

Comment: "..2" is probably an artifact from within `summary(glm)` where you are pulling the fitted values. It shouldn't effect your output and your answer below should avoid it.